# Upgrade rails version permission denied rvm folder /bin/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to install rails 3.2.20 with ruby2.2.0.

So with rvm I make

rvm install 2.2.0

After I make

gem install rails -v 3.2.20

After rvm use default ruby-2.2.2

But when I try rails -v, I have the error

-bash: /home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rails: Permission denied

Why? I try also chmod -R 777 on .rvm but nothing change

If I try

which ruby I have

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby

If I try whch rails I have nothing

Answer (score 0):

- check if you are logged in as the correct user
- check if the permissions of the user’s home directory are correct, e.g. /home/xxx/
- remove the ruby under /usr/local/bin
- reinstall rvm if all fails